# How to make sure that an insert command completed and the table has been updated?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-sqlite

Assume that there are 2 threads, one thread inserts data to the database via  a ContentProvider.
After the insert statement, callback a method to query the database in the anohter thread.
However, sometimes it is possible that the query finishes before the table has been updated.
So the new data can not been fetched.

Is there a method to make the insert command really complete?
Then calling the query method would return the new inserted data.

Comment: However, some times it is possible that the query finished before the table has been update.  which query you are refering? insert or fetch?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa fetch. when fetching, the table does not update after insert.

Comment: The `insert()`, `update()` and `delete()` methods return the number of affected records.

Comment: @BobMalooga yeah, I know it. But would that could help me solve this problem?

Comment: If the affected records are **> 0**, then the command was successful.

Comment: @BobMalooga I'm sure that the command was successful. Just when I some times query the database, the database is refreshing, not prepared well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert is finished when the `insert()` method returns in that thread. If another thread depends on that, you must then send a message from the first to the second thread.

Comment: Actually, I use `loader` to automatically query when there is any change in database. And use `AsyncQueryHandler` to insert. I don't know whether the process executed in the background as what you said: when I call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`, the database has been really update or it is being executed.